# Not being able to pass a variable from Express to EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I can't figure out where I messed up. When I try to render this in my browser it simply says.

```
ReferenceError: /views/login.ejs:14
12|   <h1>
13|     Value:
>> 14|     <span id="val"><%= val %></span>
15|   </h1>
16| </body>
17| 

val is not defined
```

App.js (Relevant Stuff, I have Express required)

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.use(session({
  secret: 'hello world',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/register', routes.register);

app.post('/register', routes.postRegister);

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login', {
    val: 'whatever'
  })
});
```

views/login.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Value:
    <span id="val"><%= val %></span>
  </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I've been stuck in this simple problem for over an hour and honestly I have absolutely no idea what it means.

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve the issue but you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the `res.render()` line.

Comment: yeah, fixed it but it wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok with the code. Probably you forgot something trivial.

This is my working setup:

```
var express = require('express');

 // Create a new Express application.
 var app = express();


 // Configure view engine to render EJS templates.
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Define routes.
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {

res.render('index', {
val: 'whatever'
});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:5000/");
```